# xcode .pch, exclude from one single file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

**.pch**

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "thing.h"
#endif
```

I have a pretty large project I'm trying to debug and I have a suspicion the problem is in thing.h

From what I understand the .pch file is included in EVERY .m and .h in the project.

Is it possible to have it not included in just one or two files? For debugging I would like to not include thing.h in just one test file, but removing it from the .pch causes a cascading nightmare across the project.

Comment: Ah the nightmare of putting user headers into pch files… Sorry this bit you; it's a good lesson on one of several reasons to avoid this practice. I don't know of a good solution. Note that pch files are included into every compile unit explicitly by Xcode, which passes `-include /path/to/generated/file.pch` to clang. I don't know of a way to work around that. It may be a good opportunity to do the very mechanical (if tedious) fix of putting headers where they are used.

Comment: Thats what we ended up doing :-/   It was a nightmare of a task but hopefully will make any future contributors job easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question but I just ran into this issue. I was able to solve the problem by wrapping the pch file with a `ifndef SOME_NAME`. Then in the project settings on each specific file I wanted it to not be included I added a compiler flag of `-DSOME_NAME=1`. Hope that helps someone in the future.